# How can I wipe the JS environment in Rhino within the interperter?

Tags: javascript, java, reset, rhino

I have a problem wherein I am loading a number of JS files and then 
executing a function in JavaScript, then I want to wipe the global 
namespace of the loaded objects, and load a different set of JS files 
before executing the next JavaScript Function.

Does anyone here know of a good way of doing this without exiting the 
Rhino JavaScript interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly you're executing scripts? Some code sample would help.

Some time ago I used it this way:

```
Object obj = ScriptableObject.getProperty (scope, methodName);
Callable fun = (Callable) obj;
Scriptable thisObj = scope;
scope = ScriptableObject.getTopLevelScope (scope);
Object result = fun.call(cx, scope, thisObj, args);
```

where scope contains all loaded objects created before and cx is an instance of Context.

So you don't exactly need to wipe anything - just use new scope.